# How to validate combination in Vertica DB

Tags: database, validation, vertica

I have a question about Vertica DB's query that I want to run.
I have a table with 5 columns, and each column can get values of 1 or 0,
I want to return all the Id of which I have combination of '1' in more than one column.
I added a pic for demonstration and I want to return all the ID of the marked rows,
regards

p.s. the value of the table can be 1/0/2, what is not allowed are that in the same row to get '1' in two rules.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I want to get all the ID's that have more than 1 times the number '1' inside them

Comment: Your question says two different things. First it says that the columns can have values of 1 or 0, then it says they can be 1/0/2. Please be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a boolean value as a number, it will have the value `1` when true, `0` when false. So you can add up the comparisons:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE (rule_1 = 1) + (rule_2 = 1) + (rule_3 = 1) + (rule_4 = 1) > 1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1be7c0/1)

In another database you can use `CASE` expressions to translate conditions to numbers:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE (CASE WHEN rule_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + (CASE WHEN rule_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + (CASE WHEN rule_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + (CASE WHEN rule_4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```

Comment: my sql not recognized the + operation

Comment: I've added a sqlfiddle demo showing that it works. Are you sure you're using MySQL as your RDBMS?

Comment: I get an error if I try it in SQL-Server, but it works in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake I am using vertica DB

Comment: Added how to do it in other databases using `CASE`.